# Input Penn Treebank constituent trees in a Stanford CoreNLP pipeline

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am using the [OpenIE](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/openie.shtml) tool from the Stanford NLP libraries to get minimal clauses from a sentence. Here is what I have come up with so far (largely inspired from their demo code):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,depparse,natlog,openie");
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

    Annotation doc = new Annotation("Obama was born in Hawaii. He is our president.");
    pipeline.annotate(doc);

    for (CoreMap sentence : doc.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {

        OpenIE split = new OpenIE(props);
        List<SentenceFragment> clauses = split.clausesInSentence(sentence);
        for (SentenceFragment clause : clauses) {
            List<SentenceFragment> short_clauses = split.entailmentsFromClause(clause);
            for (SentenceFragment short_clause : short_clauses){
                System.out.println(short_clause.parseTree);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I now want to use PTB constituent trees as input instead of plain text and then only use the *depparse*, *natlog* and *openie* annotators to get the clauses.

I know that I can use PTB trees as input to the Stanford parser (as explained [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/parser-faq.shtml#s)) but have not figured out how to integrate that in the pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is I think actually nontrivial. If someone has a clean way to do this in the pipeline, chime in! But, if I were to do it I'd probably just call the component bits of code manually. This means:

- Create a `SemanticGraph` object from the `GrammaticalStructure` from the constituency tree.
- Add a lemma annotation to each `IndexedWord` in the semantic graph. This can be done by calling `Morphology#lemma(word, posTag)` on each token, and setting the `LemmaAnnotation` to this.
- Running through the natural logic annotator is going to be tricky. One option is to mock an Annotation object and push it through the usual `annotate()` method. But, if you don't care too much about the OpenIE system recognizing negation, you can skip this annotator by adding the value `Polarity#DEFAULT` to each token in the `SemanticGraph` on the `PolarityAnnotation` key.
- Now your dependency tree should be ready to pass through the OpenIE annotator. You want to make three calls here:

  - `OpenIE#clausesInSentence(SemanticGraph)` will generate a collection of clauses from a given graph.
  - `OpenIE#entailmentsFromClause(SentenceFragment)` will generate short entailments from each clause. You want to pass each of the outputs from the above function into this, and collect all the resulting fragments.
  - `OpenIE#relationsInFragment(SentenceFragment)` will segment a short entailment into a relation triple. It returns an `Optional` -- most fragments don't segment into any triple. You want to pass each of the short entailments collected from the above call into this function, and collect the relation triples that are defined in the output of this function. These are your OpenIE triples.

Out of curiosity, what are you trying to do in the end? Perhaps there's an easier way to accomplish the same goal.

Comment: I am trying to get the clauses from the PTB corpus to use them as input to a microplanning task. 
I only need the clauses and not the triples.
How could I mock an Annotation object to be able to call the `annotate()` method ?

Comment: OK, then you can skip the natural logic annotations -- just add the default polarity to each token. You can also skip the last two calls in OpenIE and just call `OpenIE#clausesInSentence(SemanticGraph)`. You will still need lemmas though. Another option is to use the traces in the Penn Treebank directly -- this is what the clause splitter is trained on anyways.